# Shorten file names in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, geotiff-tiff

I am working on Modis products. They usually have names like:
 "MYD11A2.A2002185.h20v05.005.2007221163754.hdf". 
I am converting these hdf files to geotiff. There is no problem with it. But I also want to build  model that shortens that names such as "2002185.tif" by removing some characters from the beginning and from the end. When I use %name% it gives the same name. Is there anybody having a suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, is the name you want consistently between the first and second periods and ignoring the first character of that text (for your example "A")?

Comment: I want to remove "MYD11A2.A" from the begining and ".h20v05.005.2007221163754.hdf" from end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calculate Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) where the input is the full file name and the result would be your shortened name that you use for inline substitution

The python function could be something like:

```
s= inputName.split(".")
outname = ".".join(map(None, s[1:-2])) + ".tif"
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you please show this in Calculate Value?

I'm trying to truncate a filename with this but all I'm getting is to make the output files 1